# С чего начать разработку программы mind map для iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Необходимо реализовать mind map на iOS (визуализация дерева с возможностью перетаскивать листы).

[image: Mind Map]

Базовый функционал: есть прямоугольники с текстом, соединенные линиями. Их можно таскать (идущая к ним линия рисуется динамически). Также если перетащить один прямоугольник на другой, должна появиться всплывающая менюшка.

Вопросы: что использовать для реализации этих прямоугольников (какие стандартные объекты/библиотеки)? Чем рисовать кривые связей? Есть ли функционал для drag'n'drop в стандартных библиотеках iOS?

Answer (score 1):

ну например:

1. UILabel
2. UIBezierPath
3. Любой объект, наследованный от UIResponder имеет функцию touchesMoved, которую вам надо переписать и сделать, чтобы фрейм объекта двигался вместе с касанием.

Comment: С объектами понял, спасибо. Есть еще вопрос - есть ли какие-то способы автоматически отрисовать такое дерево?

Comment: надо по github пошуршать. я думаю что то найдется